# Why Oracle throwing fatal error during impdp?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, impdp

I am getting the below Oracle error while importing a dump locally to my computer this error occurs after half the file were imported successfully

```
impdp data1/data1 directory=data1_RESTORE dumpfile=data1_22OCT18_%U.dmp logfile=data_log transform=disable_archive_logging:Y METRICS=Y
```

> ORA-39014: One or more workers have prematurely exited.

Comment: This is a generic message, probably indicating a system error. You need to find the trace file produced by the failure.

Comment: [Finding trace files](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/diag.htm#ADMIN12484)

Comment: Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 1 seq# 1873 mem# 0: 
Errors in file C:\APP\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\DATA\DATA\trace\DATA_dw00_17172.trc  (incident=7626):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qmcxeRemapCollide1], [7013], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Incident details in: C:\APP\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\DATA\DATA\incident\incdir_7626\DATA_dw00_17172_i7626.trc
Sun Nov 11 09:31:50 2018
Dumping diagnostic data in directory=[cdmp_20181111093150], requested by (instance=1, osid=17172 (DW00)), summary=[incident=7626].
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.